# cheerio script element - data

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Im using cheerio to do some scraping and want to access the head js element on a page (notably instructables). I can access it but it comes back as function.

So using this:

```
  console.log($('script').attr('type', "application/ld+json").text);
```

- (on this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-an-online-Fish-Tank-webcam!/step3/Cut-the-project-box/)
- this provides 'Function'
- I thought strinify would work but it doesn't :(

Comment: text() is a function to get the text content of the tag, which is probably empty if the script has a .src. what are you trying to get?

Comment: It's not a src. It's the content of a script tag. .text and .data seem to be giving the same thing. https://runkit.com/58d97359d2dfbd0014d162e2/58d97359d2dfbd0014d162e3

Answer (score 8):

This is because `$("script").attr("type","application/ld+json");` returns an array of script tags (there's more than only one script tag on the page) and it's also changing the type of all script tag of the page to `application/ld+json`

[See JQuery .attr() documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

If you need to get the one with that type `$("script[type='application/ld+json']")` will do the trick.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-an-online-Fish-Tank-webcam!/step3/Cut-the-project-box/', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var obj = $("script[type='application/ld+json']"); 

    for(var i in obj){
        for(var j in obj[i].children){
            var data = obj[i].children[j].data;
            if(data){
               console.log(data);
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right but something isnt right! There is only one script with type "application/ld+json" - so how come its coming back with an array? 
https://runkit.com/58d97359d2dfbd0014d162e2/58d97359d2dfbd0014d162e3

Comment: @willwade sorry I was mistaken. The way you were doingt it was totally wrong, you were changing the type of all the script tags in the page. It's now fixed in my code.

Comment: @antoine you are missing a closing brace - should be $("script[type='application/ld+json']") :-)